# Unicode characters in HAML/Sinatra/Passenger errors

Tags: apache, sinatra, haml, passenger

If I put this into my HAML,

```
:ruby
  foo = "2".asdf
%p ss
```

I get, as expected, this error from Sinatra:

```
NoMethodError at /
undefined method `asdf' for "2":String
```

But when I have a **UNICODE CHARACTER** in my HAML:

```
:ruby
  foo = "2".asdf
%p ß
```

I no longer get the error but instead Apache crashes ("500 Internal Server Error") with `Premature end of script headers:` outputted into the Apache error log.

Can someone explain why Sinatra error messages are not liking unicode characters elsewhere in the HAML? I should mention that unicode chars are working fine when no errors appear.

By the way, I have of course done `set :show_exceptions, true` in my Sinatra app (in development mode), which is why the errors show up in the first place.

Comment: I see from the [other question you asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312365/haml-a-very-weird-indentation-difference-bug) that you're using Haml v4.0.0  with Ruby 1.9.3. Do you still get the error if you run the code without Sinatra in the console? i.e. `s = ":ruby\n  foo = "2".asdf\n%p ss\n"` then `Haml::Engine.new(s).render` and the same with the unicode version. I get errors with both.