# HAML - a very weird indentation difference - bug?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

This HAML

```
%script{:type => "text/javascript"}
  :plain
    $(document).ready(function() {
      bar();
      var foo = foo_func("#{}");
    });
```

as expected gives this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    bar();
    var foo = foo_func("");
  });
</script>
```

But this **ALMOST IDENTICAL** HAML (changed only `bar()`to `prep()`):

```
%script{:type => "text/javascript"}
  :plain
    $(document).ready(function() {
      prep();
      var foo = foo_func("#{}");
    });
```

gives this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  prep();
  var foo = foo_func("");
});
</script>
```

**NOTE THE MESSED UP INDENTATION** in the second case.

Why would changing `bar()`to `prep()` cause this weird difference?

Comment: i don't know about the indentation, but you know there is a :javascript filter, right?

Comment: The short explanation for this is that `pre` in `prep()` is matching a regex looking for the `<pre>` tag in order to handle whitespace (changing `prep` to `code` will also produce the same result). I think it was introduced in 3.1.5 (https://github.com/haml/haml/commit/be97a90bf002e3ffaca03cb71a53df011d6206ff), and as far as I can tell it doesn’t happen in 4.0.0, so you should probably upgrade if you can.

Comment: I’ve just noticed the regex in that commit is wrong. Changing `prep` to `<textarea` also produces it, but just `textarea` doesn’t. Looks like a bug in the 3-1 branch.

Comment: @matt I looked into my gems folder of my particular ruby version I'm using with Passenger/Sinatra/HAML (~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems) and I see only "haml-4.0.0", so it looks like I'm using 4.0.0. So it's a bug in 4.0.0 too? Do you have expertise enough to fix it for the upcoming 4.0.1? :)

Comment: @user2015453 You’re right, it still happens in 4.0.0. It is fixed in 4.0.1.rc.1 though, which is what I was running.

Comment: @matt cool feel free to post an answer so it can be accepted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is being caused by the characters `pre` in `prep()` matching a regex that Haml is using to deal with whitespace.

In Haml you use whitespace to specify the contents of elements, and normally this is okay since when viewing HTML whitespace is “squashed” so that it appears as a single character. However, whitespace is important in some HTML elements (`pre`, `code` and `textarea`), and Haml tries to detect and deal with these elements. In this case the regex is matched and the block after the first line isn’t indented.

This code has been changed in the latest version (currently 4.0.1.rc.1) and this doesn’t happen in that version. I’ve also created a [pull request that fixes the regex in the 3-1 branch](https://github.com/haml/haml/pull/649).